# Как определить на одной странице два Angular'a?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такой код:

```
<div ng-app="points" ng-init="points = [1,2,3]" ng-controller = 'myPoints'>
    <p>Third is {{points[2]}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}</p>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var points = angular.module ("points", []);
    var myApp = angular.module ('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = 'dick';
        $scope.lastName = 'steel';
    })
</script>
```

Вместе дивы не работают, но если один закомментировать, то другой работает. Как это решить? В скрипте я их инициализирую

Comment: а зачем вам два ng-app?

Comment: @Grundy не знаю, тренируюсь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете инициализировать приложение дважды с помощью ng-app, цитата из документации angular:

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. **To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead**.

Вместо этого используйте [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Comment: Спасибо большое, спецификация это дело)